# Is it normal to change methods behaviour to test them?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a class:

```
class MotorControl
{
    private:
        IAccelStepper *motor;
        IEncButton2<EB_ENCBTN> *encoder;
    
    public:
        void processEncoder();
        void returnToOrigin();
        void switchStep();
};
```

And its method that I want to test:

```
void MotorControl::processEncoder()
{
    if (encoder->held())
        returnToOrigin();
    else if (encoder->click())
        switchStep();
}
```

In my test, I want to know if the method (e.g. returnToOrigin()) was called. I know about mocks but I dont need to mock entire class so I can't write interface and mock it. GoogleTest API explained how to mock non-vurtual methods, but it requires to add a template. Also I had an idea to make this function non-void (e.g. int) and return something in every case.

I'm curious to know if it is a normal practice to expand(change) behaviour of your class only for tests. Maybe instead of mocking part of its method I should control output state, but if some method uses a lot of parameters is it normal to check every?
I'd appreciate any help and advices.

Comment: No, methods under test shouldn't change their behavior or even know they run under test or not. You may be seriously sued for doing such, like Volkswagen, Audi or Mercedes just experience.

Comment: it is not too uncommon to modify a method so it becomes testable. It happens less often if you start by writing the test and only then implement the method. But if you want to test a method you should test that method, not some other method

Comment: On one hand, being unable to test a class can be a sign of it being poorly designed. On the other hand, maybe you're testing something that shouldn't be tested (why can't you detect the effects `returnToOrigin()`, as opposed to checking whether it was called?).

Comment: btw I suggest you to change your pov. Its not "only for tests" but testing is an essential part of the development cycle. If you do not test you will write broken code, so its not "only for test" but you write testable code to get code that has less bugs.

Comment: To test make an abstract baseclass (interface) for your current class. Then from the code using your class let it use the interface instead (and inject it there). Then for unit testing you can make mock/stub implementations and use those. And yes you really should try to avoid changing behavior of code under test based on whether a test is running or not. Lookup : Dependency injection + Unit testing

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can detect the effects of `returnToOrigin()` but wouldn't this be a retest of this method? Or because of testing it before that, I will be able to say for sure that this particular function was called?

Comment: I don't see a problem with redundant testing (not sure if it even counts as redundant). I also think (even though I'm not familiar with your code, of course), that it's an implementation detail of `processEncoder` what exactly it calls to return to origin. Maybe you'll later have some other way of doing it (say, `returnToOrigin` gets renamed to `returnToOriginUnchecked`, a new function `returnToOrigin` is added that checks some preconditions and then calls the old one, but `processEncoder` doesn't care about the preconditions and calls `returnToOriginUnchecked` directly).

Comment: To reiterate what HolyBlackCat said, don't test implementation, test behavior. I find your question *"wouldn't this be a retest of this method"* as an indication that you fell victim to the wrong mindset about testing software. If you think good coverage means testing every method individually, then you'll end up at the place where testing is deemed "cumbersome" or "painful" due to every refactor breaking some test.

Comment: You write a test for a function so that you can test it for the correctness of its outcomes for different states and inputs. If you leave out particular test of the outcomes because you did those tests already for the function that was called internally in that function, you then might get problems if you start to do rewrites of the code if you e.g. for some reason inline the code of that internally called function. And if you then change that function that you called internally.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica If I get it right, if, for example,my method `processEncoder` should change coordinate or step, I should check only coordinate and step in test and don't bother about anything else?

Comment: I'd say so. Check the behavior you want out of the public API. If it accomplishes it by calling some other public API, that's fine. But don't check that it *called* it, check that the outcome is as you expect.

Comment: That's not to say you shouldn't ever check things are called, just that this isn't a good use case here. If instead you had a class that accepts some sort of observer that it notifies on certain events, that it makes perfect sense to pass it a mock observer and check that you get the notifications you expect. If the notifying class changes internally, you still expect it to notify the observer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I wouldn't just say "test behavior". I would further narrow it down to say "Only test public observable behavior for any given function or class". In a library, only write tests for public API. For an application, refactor the business logic into a library and test the exported API of that library. Internal 'tests' are done with asserts. If you feel the need to rigorously test some internals of the library, the library is too big and should be refactored into multiple smaller libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious to know if it is a normal practice to expand(change) behaviour of your class only for tests

No, if by this you mean that your method would have a different behavior, logic or implement a different algorithm when ran through a test versus normal operation.

Yes, if by this you mean change the method syntax or api  so that it can be properly tested.

For example even though in your app you only use one type of motor and one type only, it's not only acceptable but recommended to create a motor interface (*) so that you can mock operations on motors. This doesn't change the way the methods work in test vs non-test env, but it does change their signature to operate on interface instead of concrete types.

*) I use interface here as an example, but it really depends on the testing framework, it can be interfaces with virtual methods, or templates or whatever the testing framework requires.